# Windows 10 fails to load after installation of any Linux distribution

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot

I try to make Windows 10 boot along the Kali Linux 2017.1 (but the following problem occurs with Ubuntu too).

Here are my partitions:
[image: Partition table (GParted)]

When I install Kali (GRUB installs to MBR) and boot Windows, it works well. But if I boot Kali, Windows fails to load (the Windows logo appears, then it restarts, and this continues till the error `0x0000001` appears). If I boot from a Windows Install image and restore the bootloader (`bcdedit #:\Windows`, `bootrec /FixBoot`, `bootrec /FixMbr`), it works well again. Till I boot Kali again. Same problem with Ubuntu. How can I solve this problem?

*Sorry for my English.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Windows 8/10 "fast startup".

When "fast startup" is on

(this setting in **Power Options->"Choose what the power button does"->"Change settings that are currently not available"->"Turn on fast startup(recommended)**"

Windows does not shut down fully but creates a system image for starting fast later from this image. This image contains loaded drivers, open files etc.

When you boot another system like Linux it accesses files on Windows partition which fact Windows recognizes later on "fast startup", reports demagged Windows partition and starts repair.

**Solution: Switch "fast startup" OFF.**